# How to set a cn locale to rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I trying to add a chinese language.I was used gem `rails i18n`, and when I make that

```
I18n.locale = :cn
```

console show me an error

```
I18n::InvalidLocale: :cn is not a valid locale
```

or that

```
I18n.locale = :"zh-CN"
```

locale do not working

how fix it?

Comment: Yes change that to `I18n.locale = :"zh-CN"` and what is your file name? it should be `zn-CN.yml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the following line to false in application.rb

```
config.i18n.enforce_available_locales = false
```